# Xpath Id of selected value/s in a list changes upon using or eliminating some values in the list - Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have this certain list which consists of unique values. The list is searchable and values can only be selected upon ticking the checkbox. Certain value can only be selected once.
Steps:

1. My problem is that when you search (ex. Value1) on the search field then the value1 will be displayed on the list with this xpath id
   `//*[@id='trustAccountForm']/div/div[2]/p[12]/label` 
   Upon getting the xpath of (value1), we need to search another value for ex (content2) this value has an xpath id of `//*[@id='trustAccountForm']/div/div[2]/p[9]/label`
2. Now if you save the transaction which has (value1) as the selected value with the said xpath id..
3. then if your going to save the (content2) with the given xpath id you can no longer select (content2) since its xpath is changed upon saving of the (value1) since the number of values in the list decreases

How can it be solve? Is it possible to just select a value in a list without indicating the locator?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, what does the locator for item 2 change to after selecting item 1?  Does the paragraph (p) change?  Division?  How is it different?

Comment: Add the relevant part of the HTML to your question or if possible the URL of the WebPage you are trying to automate.

Comment: @BillHileman yes the p[9] changed. All the values in the list have  //*[@id='trustAccountForm']/div/div[2]/p[number]/label as an xpath id format what changes is the p[number]

Comment: What I'm not following though, is that they should be in numbered order in the document, so if you select paragraph 12 first, it should only renumber the paragraphs higher in number, but your description makes it sound like it's changing paragraph 9?.  If it's the other way around, and selecting 9 changes 12 to 11, I can understand, then the solution in your case would be to select higher numbers to lower numbers in sequence, if possible.